# Arduino computer mouse/input device

Tags: c, arduino, mouse, processing, usbserial

I have successfully talked to the computer from an Arduino via serial USB port and I had the idea that I could make a keyboard or mouse with the arduino. Say I wanted to translate the computer's mouse 1 pixel to the left. What message would I have to send over the serial line in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is a wonderful thing.  ["use arduino as mouse"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=use+arduino+as+mouse) returns 1.7 million hits.  The [third hit on the list](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) takes you to the `Arduino Playground` for an example using the new Leonardo board.

Note:
`The Leonardo differs from all preceding boards in that the ATmega32u4 has built-in USB communication, eliminating the need for a secondary processor. This allows the Leonardo to appear to a connected computer as a mouse and keyboard, in addition to a virtual (CDC) serial / COM port.`

Assuming you don't have that board, here is [another site](http://hunt.net.nz/users/darran/) for some other specific boards and [yet another](http://code.rancidbacon.com/ProjectLogArduinoUSB) that is log for a project including hardware and software for older boards.

Hope this helps (and is a better answer to the question).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reconfigure the USB interface chip to appear as a USB HID endpoint.